# Supressing fgetcsv warning

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I have the following function to get a csv file form a third party resource:

```
    public function getSubject()
    {       
        $file   =  fopen( $this->url , 'r');
        $result = array();
        while ( ( $line = fgetcsv( $file )) !== false ) {
            if ( array(0 => null) !== $line ) {
                $result[] = $line;
            }
        }

        fclose( $file );
        $this->setSubject( $result );
    }
```

The problem arises when the third party csv file is unavailable, I get this error:

> PHP Warning:  fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in /var/www/html/code.php on line 57

What is the best way to test for this error?

Comment: invest some time in researching after using the `if` clause and the boolean data type. also, look at the documentation of the `fopen` function, especially why it returns a boolean value.

Comment: Well test the `$file` variable of course after the `fopen()` [Or R.T.M](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test `$file` after you open it.

```
$file = fopen($this->url, 'r');
if (!$file) {
    die("Unable to open URL");
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this was quite obvious, been a long long coding session.